# How to add Search Filter in React Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown component as shown below: (For Reproduction go to this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-fire-3dxqr?file=/src/TextDropDown.js))

[image]

I want to add `search to filter functionality` that allows to filter the dropdown elements, based on the query: `this.DropDownElements.includes(searchParameter)`.
constructor(props)
{
super(props);

```
        this.DropDownElements = this.props.Values.map((element,ind) => ({
            value: element,
            isChecked: false,
            id: "DropdownElems:" + this.props.UniqueIdentifier + ind,

        }));

        this.ConstantDropDownElements = this.props.Values.map((element,ind) => ({
            value: element,
            isChecked: false,
            id: "DropdownElems:" + this.props.UniqueIdentifier + ind,

        }));
    }
```

I am storing `searchParameter` value in `this.state.Value`.

```
state = {

        isEditing: false,
        isFirstOnChange: true,
        isDropDownOpen: false,
        isMultiSelectOn: true,
        elements: this.DropDownElements,
        placeholder: this.props.PlaceHolderText,
        Value: "",
        GlobalFilters: [
                                {
                                    selection: "Select All",
                                    isSelected: false,
                                },
                                {
                                    selection: "Clear All",
                                    isSelected: false,
                                },
                        ],

    };
```

Now here comes the challenging part. When I search in the search box, I want to perform autofilter and then make the selections. What I tried is creating an unaffected DropDown as initialized in `constructor` and then filtering the `DropDownElements` based on the search parameter passed. But then mapping the `isChecked` key of the object is getting very complex to me. Does anyone have a simple solution and approach for the same?

My current Component allows to select and de-select without losing the state (during the collapse and open of dropdown), my final goal is to add a search query feature which filters up the data, and then when I make the selection it should be mapped correctly to the right element of the `DropDownElements`.